# code_builder required build_value

Tags: flutter

Just upgraded flutter beta channel. Want to update build_value ^6.1.0 as a dependency. but getting error:

```
 Because code_builder 3.1.2 depends on built_value ^5.1.0 and no 
 versions of code_builder match >3.1.2 <4.0.0, code_builder ^3.1.2 
 requires built_value ^5.1.0.
 So, because zoombox depends on both code_builder ^3.1.2 and built_value 
 ^6.1.0, version solving failed.
```

downgrading built_value to 5.1.0 causing more error because of other dependency. code_builder 3.1.2 is latest version.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue https://github.com/dart-lang/code_builder/issues/219

It's probably best to stick with `built_value: ^5.1.0` until fixed.
You can try `dependency_overrides:` to overrule pub, but that is error-prone.

Not tested myself but this should do it

```
dependency_overrides: 
  built_value: ^6.1.0
```

Beware, there is no guarantee `built_value: 6.1.0` and `code_builder: ^3.1.2` will work well together.

Please don't forget to upvote the issue.

Comment: dependency_overrides:
  build_value: '5.1.0'  ?

Comment: can you add proper way to add dependency_override?

Comment: `dependency_overrides: built_value: ^6.1.0` should do it.

Comment: Because zoombox depends on build_value any which doesn't exist (could not find package build_value at https://pub.dartlang.org), version solving failed.

Comment: It's `built_value` not `build_value` ;-).